# Customizing header in gsm-l class

Tags: header-footer, amsmath, amsbook

I use gsm-l class, a derived class from amsbook, to write my mathbook. However, it happened that on the header, the same number of chapter and section appear, like this (number 1 on the left is chapter number, on the right is the section number).

[image]

I want to remove the number in front of each chapter's name and section's name or customize the number in front of chapter's name to Roman number. So, what could I do?

Here is a  MWE.

```
\documentclass{gsm-l}
\usepackage[papersize={160mm,240mm},inner=20mm, outer=15mm, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\geometry{includeheadfoot}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{section}{chapter}
\makeatother
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{This is the first chapter}
\section{This is the first section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: not relevant to the question, but i'm surprised you didn't get an error message from `\usepackage{makeidx}`.  that function is already built into `amsbook`, so there would be duplicate definitions.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this to your preamble :

```
\makeatletter
\def\partrunhead#1#2#3{%
  \@ifnotempty{#2}{{\@ifnotempty{#1}{#1 }}\@ifnotempty{#3}{}}#3}
\let\chapterrunhead\partrunhead
\let\sectionrunhead\partrunhead
\makeatother
```

(Short) Explanation : I searched into `gsm-l.cls` which commands were responsible for the page headers, and found that it was `\partrunhead`.
Here, we just modify the definition of `\partrunhead`, removing the page number and the dot.
Note that we have to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because of `\@ifnonempty`.

**Edit** : now, you should get what you want, or might be able to modify this code in order to do so :

```
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{section}{chapter}
\def\partrunhead#1#2#3{%
  \@ifnotempty{#2}{{\@ifnotempty{#1}{#1 }}\@ifnotempty{#3}{}} Chapter  \Roman{chapter} : #3}
\let\chapterrunhead\partrunhead
\def\sectionrunhead#1#2#3{ %
   \@ifnotempty{#2}{{\@ifnotempty{#1}{#1 }}\@ifnotempty{#3}{}} \arabic{section}. #3}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What should I do if I want to display the left header like: Chapter 1:This is chapter 1 and the the right header 1. The first section? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: @Knumber10, I edited my answer.